# Why are my images not changing in UICollectionView with the indexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swift2

I have a Collection View with the ImageCollectionViewClass that I have defined as well as a class for the image. However the images in the collection view aren't changing with the indexPath and I can't work out why

```
class metricImage {
    var featuredImage: UIImage!

    init(featuredImage: UIImage!){
        self.featuredImage = featuredImage
    }

    static func createImage() -> [metricImage] {
        return [metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodOne.png")!), metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodTwo.png")!), metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodThree.png")!),metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodFour.png")!),metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodFive.png")!),metricImage(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "prodSix.png")!)]
    }


}

class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{

    var images: metricImage! {
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!

    private func updateUI() {
        featuredImageView?.image! = images.featuredImage
    }

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == prodCollectionView {
        //print("collectionViewOne")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("productCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        print(indexPath.item)
        cell.images = self.prodImage[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
```

I have added some statements to make sure it enters where it needs to. I am new to swift so it may be trivial. Thank you in advance

Comment: Where and how is the 'prodImage' defined?

Comment: @Laffen  private var prodImage = metricImage.createImage()

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you're trying to achieve here, do you want the images to render in a specific order?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. I wasn't assigning the images to an outlet on my ImageClass Controller